# Unable to click on a button with id in protractor for end to end test

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor, ionic4

I am trying to click on a button to further execute the end to end test, but I am unable to do so.

I tried:

```
element(by.id('cancel-button')).click(); 
element(by.css('#cancel-button')).click(); 
element(by.ClassName('ng-star-inserted ion-color ion-color-white button button-solid ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrated button-small')).click();
```

Error:

Unable to find the element by specific locator

But nothing is working. I have attached the screenshot of the result, after inspecting the element. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Try  element(by.css(‘#cancel-button button’)).click. You have to target the button inside that tag IMO

Comment: @fastAsTortoise ' No element found using locator: By(css selector, #cancel-button button)'

Comment: Use probably another selector but try to do click on inside button element that should work. something like  element(by.id('#cancel-button')).element(by.tagName('button'));

Comment: @RichS 'No element found' error

Comment: Does `element.byCss('ion-button')` return a found set of element(s)?

Comment: @RichS There are other ion-buttons as well on the same page. How can I distinguish with this one?

Comment: `element.byCss('ion-button[id=cancel-button]')` (but make sure the cancel-button is in the list returned by the `element.byCss('ion-button')`. If anything, that list will tell you what `ion-button`'s you can interact with)

Comment: @fastAsTortoise still 'Error'

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: @fastAsTortoise No element found with the selector...

Comment: are you able to interact with other element ?

Comment: @fastAsTortoise Yes, I am able to interact with other items. This ion-button has some issue. It's not recognizable

Comment: @RichS ion-button is not recognizable. I tried is.Present and it cannot find it

Comment: do you have other button on any page that can interact with ?

Comment: @fastAsTortoise Yes, I have a button on another page and I am able to interact with it via:  const buttonElement = element(by.css('button[type="submit"]'));
            buttonElement.submit();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191483/discussion-between-fastastortoise-and-marium-malik).

Comment: Sounds like it's either not there or else inside an iframe

Comment: @pguardiario It is present as I am verifying the opened page via URL, just above it. Seems to be hidden somewhere. Not sure, how to get it

Comment: If you haven't already tried, it might be worth doing a hail mary `browser.sleep(5000)` just before the click, just to be good and sure that the page is fully loaded.  You don't have `browser.ignoreSynchronization` set to `true` do you?

Comment: Open the selenium browser's developer tools and look for it in the elements panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
     // click the element
var element = element(by.id('cancel-button')); 
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",element);
```

Comment: - Failed: javascript error: Cannot read property '0' of null
    (Session info: headless chrome=74.0.3723.0)
[0409/100838.884:INFO:CONSOLE(77058)] "ERROR", source: http://localhost:4200/vendor.js (77058)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: Element is not found. Could it be hidden under something?

Comment: add some wait . confirm whether there no frames

Answer (score 0):

You can try following selectors:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('ion-button', 'Cancel appointment '));
```

or

```
element(by.buttonText('Cancel appointment'));
```

Comment: - Failed: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("ion-button", "Cancel appointment ")

Comment: What text on "cancel button" displayed on UI

Comment: Same as the one mentioned by you

Comment: @MariumMalik did you find the solution for this issue? even i am facing the same issue